# Horizontal stack with forms

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm looking for a full-width form with two elements:

```
___________________________________
|     Text-Input     |   Button   |
‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
```

The button should have a fixed width, although the window (a mobile viewport) is of unknown size. The input size should be as wide as possible... Tough thing is input elements are hard to tame...

So far, I've got some progress with a wrapper around the input and floating http://dabblet.com/gist/2714788 (I had to put the button before the input in html though). Is there a better way?

Comment: Have you tried anything? What are you having problems with? Perhaps create a jsfiddle. As your question stands, it seems more like a requirement doc.

Comment: Yeah, I felt like that too. I guess I'll go with a dabblet. http://dabblet.com/gist/2714788

Comment: What's wrong with this? http://jsbin.com/uxofop/edit#javascript,html,live (just forget on the button fixed width.)

Comment: The issue is smaller screens might break the button contents. I'd rather leave it fixed or with a min-width.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form>
<input placeholder="This is not easy...">
<button>Submit</button>    
</form>
```

Try to use this code for the form and use this style for the input

```
input { width:80%; float:left; }
```

And this for the button

```
button { width:19%; float:left; }
```

Use this code and will work.

Comment: What happens if the viewport gets too thin and the button has some words in it (not just 'play')?